# Converting EML's to MSG's

Tags: c#, outlook, msg, eml

We have a webapplication that allows users to view emails in a table and double click on them to open them in outlook.

For that we use the (simplified) piece of code:

```
 var email = Session.OpenSharedItem(filename) as MailItem;
```

This works for .msg messages, but there are also .eml files listed in the tables. OpenSharedItem method cannot open .eml files (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176433(v=office.12).aspx)

*So we would like to convert those .eml files to .msg files.*

So far we have only found answers in paid third party libraries like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) *which we cannot do*. Are there any other solutions available?

Edit: Made more clear that we cannot use paid third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to shell out, outlook.exe can just run emls without conversion like so

```
outlook.exe /eml "path\to\file.eml"
```

This even works if the email is editable (`X-Unsent= 1`).
There may even be a way to do an equivalent [without shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27421967/2518317) which would be nice.

Alternatively though, you can do this programatically, but requires conversion; in fact you have to if you want any editable email to automatically insert the user's signature (as that would be an oft, not an msg/eml).
Below I have a powershell **script that takes an eml and conditionally either saves out an msg or an oft**, and then opens it.

You can make it just convert without opening, or just open without converting (but you do still need to make temporary files: OOM does not accept making `MailItem`s from memory); I'm just covering all bases for posterity.
What I use it for is the [eml file extension is associated to open with the script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281280/2518317) on the clients machines, they double-click an eml file, it opens in outlook.

<sub>Even though it's powershell, C# is pretty interchangable; I mean I wrote it reading only examples and documentation for C# (maybe some vbs for the old CDO).

I dont know C#, and feel putting this here will be magnitudes more help to someone seeing this post than not writing anything (since I had to scour the internet and do it from scratch).

I'll glady accept any edit if someone ports it</sub>

```powershell
$location = $PSScriptRoot
Start-Transcript "$location\LOG.txt" -Append

#ADODB only works if MIME is at the top
. {
    'MIME-Version: 1.0'
    Get-Content $args[0] <#-AsByteStream#>
} $args[0] | Set-Content "$location\tmp" <#-AsByteStream#>

#parse the eml
$eml = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Stream
$eml.Open()
$eml.LoadFromFile("$location\tmp")
$eml.Flush()
$email = New-Object -ComObject "CDO.Message"
$email.DataSource.OpenObject($eml, "_Stream")
$email.DataSource.Save()
$eml.Close()

#!moved this to the bottom to demonstrate no-shellingout and msg conversion
#if the email is not editable, just open it normally
#if ($email.Fields('urn:schemas:mailheader:X-Unsent').Value -ne '1') {
#   & "${env:ProgramFiles}\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /eml $args[0]
#   exit
#}

#build the template
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$output = $outlook.CreateItem(<#olMailItem#>0)
$output.Sender = $email.From
$output.To = $email.To
$output.CC = $email.CC
$output.BCC = $email.BCC
$output.Subject = $email.Subject
if ($email.ReplyTo) {
    $output.ReplyRecipients.Add($email.ReplyTo) | Out-Null
}
$output.BodyFormat = <#olFormatHTML#>2
$output.HTMLBody = $email.HTMLBody

#for each of the attachments
. {for ($part = $email.HTMLBodyPart; $part = $part.Parent) {
    $part.BodyParts | Where-Object {
        $_.Fields('urn:schemas:httpmail:content-disposition-type').Value -match '^(inline|attachment)$'
    }
}} | %{
    #get the name
    $name = ($_.FileName -replace '^.*[/\\]','').trim('.')
    #make one if it didnt have one
    if (!$name) {
        $name = (
            'Untitiled attachment' +
            ($_.Fields('urn:schemas:httpmail:content-media-type').Value `
                -replace '[/\\]'    ,'.' `
                -replace '^\.+|\.+$','' `
                -replace '^(.)'     ,' $1'
            )
        )
    }
    #save the attachment to file
    $_.
        GetDecodedContentStream().
        SaveToFile("$location\$name", <#adSaveCreateOverWrite#>2)

    #TODO unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem
    if ($_.Charset -imatch 'UTF-8') {
        Get-Content "$location\$name" | Out-File 'tmp' -encoding utf8
        Move-Item 'tmp' "$location\$name" -Force
    }
    #pull it into the email
    $attachment = $output.Attachments.Add("$location\$name").PropertyAccessor
    Remove-Item "$location\$name"

    #set up its properties
    if ($_.Fields('urn:schemas:mailheader:content-id').Value) {
        $attachment.SetProperty(
            <#PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID(unicode)#>'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F',
            $_.Fields('urn:schemas:mailheader:content-id').Value.trim('<>')
        )
    }
    if ($_.Fields('urn:schemas:httpmail:content-media-type').Value) {
        $attachment.SetProperty(
            <#PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG(unicode)#>'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F',
            $_.Fields('urn:schemas:httpmail:content-media-type').Value
        )
    }
}

#save and open the email
if ($email.Fields('urn:schemas:mailheader:X-Unsent').Value -eq '1') {
    $output.SaveAs("email.oft", <#olTemplate#>2)
    $output.Close(<#olDiscard#>1)
    $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("email.oft").Display()
}
else {
    $output.SaveAs("email.msg", <#olMSG#>3)
    $output.Close(<#olDiscard#>1)
    $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem("email.msg").Display()
}
#!as per the above #!; I would normally not have the x-unset test here
#!and would only save the template, but calling it simply 'tmp', so no leftover files are made
Remove-Item "$location\tmp"
```

I think I've covered everything. This works with attachments, embedded images and css, but assumes HTML email and utf8 for attachments that are text.
That's what I needed, and although it wouldn't be hard to add support for other stuff, if you are private, or can use paid 3rd party, Dmitry seems to have done a fantastically holistic thing with Redemption (I have seen his avatar A LOT in my recent travels) and will be much simpler for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IConverterSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960231.aspx) object (native Outlook MIME converter), but it is only accessible in C++ or Delphi. Also note that as of Outlook 2016, an instance of that object can only be created when running inside the outlook.exe address space (e.g. from a COM addin).

You can also create your own converter and create an EML file one MIME header at a time using a third party library (I used [Lumisoft](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/net/help/html/4b7385dc-adc3-ca0f-0736-bbd5d5bdc8fe.htm) in the past).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it can run in a service, unlike the Outlook Object Model), and the conversion is as simple as

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  set Msg = Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp\test.msg")
  Msg.SaveAs "c:\temp\test.eml", 1031
```