# How can I associate a file type with a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have a very powershell script that works perfectly and does:

```
Param(
  [string]$fileName
) 

echo "Woo I opened $fileName"
```

When I run it on the command line, it works:

```
my-script.ps1 .\somefile
```

Returns:

```
Woo I opened somefile
```

I would like to associate `my-script.ps1` with a particular file type. I am attempting to do this via 'Open With'  However:

- Windows doesn't include Powershell scripts as 'Programs' (though it considers CMD and batch scripts as 'Programs')

[image]

- When I pick 'All Files' instead, and pick my powershell script, Windows shows this message

[image]

**How can I associate a file type with a Powershell script?**

Comment: This question has had more than 2500 views now - I wonder if @rich-turner feels like bugging the Windows team to add `ps1` to the list alongside `com` and `bat`. 

Comment: Unfortunately, even though this is tagged with Windows-10, the cmd options no longer work.  I learned this after struggling too long.  Only XML routes work.  I'm not certain the cutoff in Windows releases, but the reference is here (first two sentences):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hewagen/making-file-type-associations-enterprise-ready

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the proper tools for the job:

```
cmd /c assoc .fob=foobarfile
cmd /c ftype foobarfile=powershell.exe -File `"C:\path\to\your.ps1`" `"%1`"
```

Note that both [`assoc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770920.aspx) and [`ftype`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771394.aspx) are CMD-builtins, so you need to run them via `cmd /c` from PowerShell.

For files without extension use this association:

```
cmd /c assoc .=foobarfile
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if `assoc` and `ftype` affect current user or local machine?  I no longer remember, but I remember that biting me.

Comment: I didn't check for non-admin users, but for a user with admin privileges the commands modify HKLM\Software\Classes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do it through Windows UI.

The goal here is to associate a type with powershell.exe, arguments to which will be

1. The powershell script
2. The target filename

To do this

1. Launch `Regedit.exe`. //disclaimer: you are editing Windows registry. *Here be tigers.*
2. Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (admin access, for all users) or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes
3. Create a key named `.<extension>`, e.g. if you want to associate *.zbs - create a key `.zbs`
4. Set it's (default) value to something like `zbsfile` -- this is a reference linking your extension to a filetype.
5. Create a key called `zbsfile` - this is your filetype
6. Set (default) value to something readable, e.g. "This file is ZBS."
7. Underneath create a tree of keys (examples are all around):

`zbsfile
  shell
   open
    command`

8. Under `command`, set (default) value to e.g.
   `powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to your\file.ps1" "%1"`
   where %1 means the file user clicked

That should work.

EDIT:
or (crazy idea), create a bat file doing just `powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to your\file.ps1" "%%1"` and select it in Windows UI...

Comment: I need to create an association with a file that has no extension (to handle launching it correctly). Is this possible?

Comment: Hrm looks like it: http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/how-do-i-create-default-association-files-no-extension

Answer (score 4):

For those like me who got here looking for general file types associations, I ended up using this function:

```
Function Create-Association($ext, $exe) {
    $name = cmd /c "assoc $ext 2>NUL"
    if ($name) { # Association already exists: override it
        $name = $name.Split('=')[1]
    } else { # Name doesn't exist: create it
        $name = "$($ext.Replace('.',''))file" # ".log.1" becomes "log1file"
        cmd /c "assoc $ext=$name"
    }
    cmd /c "ftype $name=`"$exe`" `"%1`""
}
```

I struggled with proper quoting from [@Ansgar Wiechers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281280/1098603) but finally got it right :)

Comment: You need to update this < cmd /c 'assoc $ext=$name' > into  
  < cmd /c "assoc $ext=$name" > then this will work. :D

Comment: @MaxBarrass HAAAAAAA :))

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concrete answer tested under Windows 7 (but should work under 10 too).  Open an administrative command shell and execute the following two lines once:

```
> assoc .ps1=Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1
> ftype Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1=%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "%1"
```

Now PS1-files are executed by PowerShell 1.0 and not opened by Notepad anymore when double-clicked in the Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my remix of @Matthieu 's great remix of @Ansgar Weichar's great answer.

Matthieu's is set up for executables, and doesn't work for powershell scripts for the same reasons the OP describes.

```
Function Set-FileAssociationToPowerShellScript($extension, $pathToScript) {

    # first create a filetype
    $filetype = cmd /c "assoc $extension 2>NUL"
    if ($filetype) {
        # Association already exists: override it
        $filetype = $filetype.Split('=')[1]
        Write-Output "Using filetype $filetype"
    }
    else {
        # Name doesn't exist: create it
        # ".log.1" becomes "log1file"
        $filetype = "$($extension.Replace('.', ''))file"
        Write-Output "Creating filetype $filetype ($extension)"
        cmd /c "assoc $extension=$filetype"
    }
    Write-Output "Associating filetype $filetype ($extension) with $pathToScript.."
    cmd /c "ftype $filetype=powershell.exe -File `"$pathToScript`" `"%1`""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For get associate app i use [!magic] :)  :

```
Set-Alias fa Get-AssocApp

#Get application by file extension Proto1
function Get-AssocApp ([string] $FileType) { 
        ((cmd /c echo ((cmd /c ftype  ( (cmd /c assoc $FileType) -replace "(.*=)*" ,"")) -replace "(.*=)","")).Replace('"','') -replace "\s%+.*$" ,"")

}
```

Out:

```
PS C:\Users\user> fa .txt
C:\WINDOWS\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE
PS C:\Users\user> fa .pdf
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe
PS C:\Users\user> fa .js
C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe
```