# How to start or attach to Outlook using Interop C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, com, interop

I'm trying to write a C# program that will either start a new instance of Outlook if none are running, or attach to the first instance if it happens to be running already.

I've found a previous discussion [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421967/how-to-run-outlook-using-process-startoutlook-exe-and-get-the-control-back) that pretty much identifies what I'm trying to achieve. The problem with the [Microsoft Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462097.aspx) is that some of my Outlook Plugins/Add-ins don't work properly, for example, iManage Filesite/Worksite. The plugin appears to be in the ribbon when Outlook starts, but some functionality is missing and if I try a search etc. Outlook stops responding and crashes. The plugins work properly if outlook is started from the console or like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"OUTLOOK.exe");
```

But then I can never attach to the running Outlook instance because

```
application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
```

Fails with a COM error (0x800401E3 MK_E_UNAVAILABLE). I can only get around this error if I debug the application and step through it. I've tried allowing time for Outlook to start, switching the active window (changing focus), but none of these options work.

Comment: Remove your accounts from outlook . Clear the PST files of outlook. Open outlook in safe mode. Add your account and wait until all folders are updated. Close and open Outlook. Try doing the same mentioned in the question again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message from GetActiveObject most likely means your code and Outlook are running in different security contexts. Make sure neither apps (or both) are running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator).

Comment: I've checked in task manager and both are running with user privileges only

Comment: They would be even if you use "Run As Administrator". How are both apps started?

Comment: I've tested starting the app from a console (non admin) and from the Visual Studio debugger (non admin). Starting from VS only works if I step over the GetActiveObject line, otherwise I get the COM error (that's why I tried switching window focus)